# Android device sends ARP request, no response

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

**Some background:**
I'm part of a team that's developing an Android game for a college course.
I am the person in charge of networking, and my aim is to have a game running in "client mode" submit input to a game running in "host mode". The host will then do all physics/collisions etc, and send back the updated state of the game.

I'm confident that I can compress the state of the game enough that sending the whole state of it will work fine (graphics will be done client-side).

I'm aiming have this game work on a wireless LAN, using IPv4 addresses that I get from

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().
```

All activity code and user input is handled outside of my code, so I'm basically working with Java sockets.

**Question:**
My code below should send a single packet of a single data byte to the host, telling it that there's client who wants to connect. However, I've used Wireshark to trace all packet activity for about 80 seconds after I run this code, and all I can see is

```
11  2.825742000 MurataMa_41:d5:ed   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.0.25?  Tell 192.168.0.24
```

That is, an unanswered ARP request. I've tried multiple ports, in case that was the problem, but I'm currently using 5000.

```
int hostPort = 5000;

hostSocket = new DatagramSocket(hostPort);
byte [] buffer = new byte[1];
buffer[0] = 'h';
DatagramPacket hello = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, hostAddress, hostPort);
hostSocket.send(hello);
```

So, how can I get the host Android device to respond to ARP requests? I have an Android 2.2 phone sending the requests, and a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2, which *should* be receiving them.

**EDIT**

I've checked LogCat output for any/all exceptions when sending. There are none.

Comment: It sounds like you are running Wireshark on a 3rd machine, which may not see traffic intended only for one of the devices such as the arp reply.  You may need to run tcpdump on one of the devices (if rooted) or on the router, or use something that is more of a wifi sniffer.  A simpler test though would be to see if you can ping one android device from a PC or the adb shell of the other - that won't work without a successful ARP.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I have successfully pinged both devices from my laptop, which is indeed the 3rd machine. I can also see ARP requests and responses from other devices on the network through the Wireshark capture on my laptop, which is why I thought that I'd be able to see an ARP response to the client device.

Comment: If you have successfully pinged (without manually adding to your arp cache), then ARP is working.  FWIW when I ping an android device from one machine and monitor from another, I see the ARP request but not the reply.

Comment: @Chris Stratton
I can see it now, thanks! Now I just have to figure out why the host isn't receiving it. Thanks for responding.

Comment: A third party machine isn't receiving traffic that is none of it's business - it's an efficiency (and to weak degree) privacy thing.  It needs to see the ARP request because it might need to answer it, but it doesn't need to see the reply or much anything else that follows.

Comment: I understand that part now. I think my last comment may have been unclear. I need to figure out why the host isn't receiving the packet, not the ARP request. ARP seems to actually be working fine. At any rate, thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can try substituting netcat (in udp mode) on the pc for either phone, in turn, and see if the results are any better.  Remember that UDP isn't guaranteed to arrive (or even arrive in order) so you'll have to build a retry mechanism.

Comment: Doesn't ARP require a raw socket?